# google vizualization wrong number format

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, number-formatting

I'm trying to format a number with thousands separator and decimal separator. In google api documentation says that by default, thousands separator is "," while decimal separator is ".", but I have to inverted to get the desire results results.

I mean, by defautl when I create a chart I get numbers like 3,50 instaed of 3.50 if I want the dot, I need a formatter with a comma decimal separator.

```
var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({pattern: "#,00"});
```

this give 3.50

var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({pattern: "#.00"});

this give 3,50

even the examples at [developers.google.com](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_axes#number-formats) are shown wrong.

My computer region is Dominican Republic, es-DO language.

can you tell me what is wrong?

Comment: Try with this one `var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({'pattern': '#.00\'%'});`

Comment: It keeps inverted. with dot I get comma, and with comma, I get dot.

Comment: Try with this pattern `pattern: '$###,###'`

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the [google charts documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#numberformat) for this information.

I would use

```
var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
  decimalSymbol: '.',
  groupingSymbol: ','
});
```

This will give you "." as decimal and it would use "," as thousand separator.